# Issue Regarding Running .ipynb file on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

After successfully importing the notebook into colab, I try to run it, but failed. Can someone tell me what the problem is? Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OihYp.jpg)

Comment: It's simple you need to upload your Flows_Clean.xlsx toypor working folder

Comment: Does this mean whenever I upload the notebook into colab, I need to make sure the files imported in the notebook should be in the folder in google drive?

Comment: The xlsx file that you try to open could not be found. So simplest way to upload it to google drive and mount your google drive in colab. Don't forget to change the path to the file.

Comment: Understand. Thank you very much!